# getting error: Python failed preconditioned when trying to train machine learning model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm using tensorflow keras for training my model. My images shape are (224, 224, 3) for trainning my image classification model. I am using VGG face weights which is why i cannot change the convolutional layers.
this is my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Input, Dropout, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Activation, \
    BatchNormalization, ZeroPadding2D, Convolution2D
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet_v2 import ResNet50V2
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import *
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.models import model_from_json
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpus[0], True)


folder = "images"
train = pd.read_csv("face_attribute_train.csv")

train_d, val_d = train_test_split(train, test_size=0.1, random_state=2)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255.,
                                   rotation_range=40,
                                   width_shift_range=0.2,
                                   height_shift_range=0.2,
                                   shear_range=0.2,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   fill_mode='nearest',
                                   horizontal_flip=True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255.)
columns = ['Thick_Lips_Nose']

trainGen = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    train_d, folder, x_col='image_id', y_col=columns, class_mode='raw', target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=128,
    color_mode='rgb', shuffle=True)
print(trainGen.image_shape)

valGen = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    val_d, folder, x_col='image_id', y_col=columns, class_mode='raw', target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=128,
    color_mode='rgb', shuffle=True)
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(4096, (7, 7), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Convolution2D(4096, (1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Convolution2D(2622, (1, 1)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate = 0.0001), metrics='accuracy')
model.load_weights("vgg_face_weights.h5")

x= Flatten()(model.layers[-3].output)
x = Dense(1748, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = Dense(874)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Dense(256)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
outputPred = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model2 = Model(inputs = model.layers[0].input, outputs = outputPred)
model2.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate = 0.0001), metrics='accuracy')

model.save("Model1/")
model2.fit(trainGen, epochs=2, validation_data=valGen)
model2.save("Model2/")
sub_df = pd.read_csv('sampleSubmission.csv')

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.)
testGen = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    sub_df, folder, x_col='image_id', y_col=None, class_mode=None, target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=128,
    color_mode='rgb', shuffle=False)
preds = []
preds = model.predict(testGen)
sub_df[['Thick_Lips_Nose']] = preds

sub_df.to_csv("Submission.csv", index=False)
sub_df
```

I am getting this error at line 105. This error is initiated by fitting of the model:

```
tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:107] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator:
 Failed precondition: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated.
     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
```

Comment: Can you share `face_attribute_train.csv` and `vgg_face_weights.h5`file to replicate your issue?